# use of $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php

In logout page I have seen use of

```
       $http_referer=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
       header('Location :'.$http_referer);
```

Where does this header redirecting page to and for what http_referrer is used for

Comment: http referer sends you back to the last page you visted. Say if you were on profiles page, then went to log out page, then after loging out you will be redirected to profiles page

Answer (score 3):

Some clients sends a [referer header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) telling you where they come from. The code in question redirects the client to that page.

Note that not all clients send the header, though. Some browsers allows you to disable the referer header. It is also seldom sent over HTTPS. Make sure you have a sensible default behavior if the header is empty.

Comment: This answer, unlike all the others, points out the two major caveats of the referer variable: not all browsers send it, and it is usually not sent at all over HTTPS. Both are worth keeping in mind.

Answer (score 0):

With the Http-Referer you can see on which page the user was before. If the user e.g. is on `http://www.google.com` and clicks on a link to you page, then in the referer will be `http://www.google.com`.

Answer (score 0):

The Referer header is sent by the browser to indicate the page the user came from, e.g. by clicking a link to your site or submitting a form.

It might not exist at all or contain something else - for example, some firewalls remove the header for (pretty questionable) "privacy" reasons. Browsers also remove it during HTTPS=>HTTP transitions.

---

However, in **your** case the logout page is most likely only accessed from your own site. So you can simply check if the referer exists and in this case use it. If it's empty you redirect e.g. to your home page:

```
$redirect_to = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : 'index.php';
header('Location: ' . $redirect_to);
```

Comment: So what we can use in place of http_referer to avoid the problem?

Comment: There is no alternative unless you have control over the referring sites (then you could pass that information as a GET parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Http Referer shows address of the page, from where the user is redirected to your page.

> According to [php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), HTTP_REFERER is the address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

Referer have following data,
if your url like : www.xyz.com/abc/text.php
then echo following:

```
echo $http_referer=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

It have print www.xyz/abc

You have go for this link: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-http-referer-variable/

That sit.